# Activate OTG on non-otg Android phone

Tags: android

I have an old LG K120 that by default doesn't have OTG. So I did what was needed (root the phone and installed a software that now tells me OTG is active) however when I try to plug a usb pen or card reader, it doesn't detect it. I hope I don't have to install a custom rom or whatever it's called risking to ruin everything. I just need to read a microSD without having to open the cover all the time.

Comment: Think that the hardware of your Android device should be OTG ready too. The USB chip. Is it?

Answer (score 0):

For running SD cards on the mobile you can use some of the pocket Wi-Fis which support SD card inside them,like some of the JioFis (check before you purchase any,if you). Then connect it to your mobile using Wi-Fi(Password protected or open) and run it.
And for running pendrives(only) you can use the SanDisk Wireless Stick pendrives, which run on Wi-Fi.
**Edit**: USB can also be used for radiation free transfer with laptop computers.(Credit goes to [blackapps](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12121419/blackapps)).

Comment: All nice to know but do you think it answers the question?

Comment: I use my the 'smart'phone only for playing mp3 and to see maps offline while hiking.. don't like getting radiations.. I'm doing like a vlog every day while backpacking and I wanted a way to edit my vids I take with other camera (not phone) to edit them on my phone.. I used to take my laptop just to transfer files so if this OTG thing worked it would really be a huge thing for me bcs less things to take with me. For the moment the only solution I have is to open phone cover every time i need to copy the vids i made with my camcorder.. not bad but I'm afraid after awhile the cover could brake.

Comment: If you want totally radiation free, then I am sorry, I can not help you.
But if you try some of the Wi-Fi sharing applications on your mobile phone like 'Xender'(no need to download on your laptop but you should have a wifi adapter installed on your laptop). I know it is not totally radiation free, but it might help.

Comment: @blackapps , What else do you think is possible to share files on a non-otg mobile phone without any hardware change or SD Card?

Comment: Usb cable to laptop would do.

Comment: @blackapps Wow,I forgot that, Using USB is a better choice. Thank you.

Comment: by looking online.. looks like this model I have LG K120 is very hard to tweak.. for instance I wanted to disable the vibration it does when I charge or connect to the computer.. but it's very hard on this model.

Comment: I see, then you can try the other methods. And I am sorry, I know nothing about the vibration.